# How to figure out for which variables a function is real

Tags: symbolic, core-language

I have

```
e[m_, n_] := Sqrt[m - n]
```

How can I figure out, using *Mathematica*, for which `m` and `n` the statement is a `Real` number?

Comment: Assuming that $m$ and $n$ are real numbers themselves, `Reduce[Sqrt[m - n] ∈ Reals, {m, n}, Reals]`. Alternatively, get right of the `Reals` domain restriction in that command for a more general result.

Comment: With version 10 or later: `FunctionDomain[Sqrt[m - n], {m, n}]`

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways to do it.

MarcoB

```
Reduce[Sqrt[m - n] ∈ Reals, {m, n}, Reals]
```

> `n <= m`

Bob Hanlon

```
FunctionDomain[Sqrt[m - n], {m, n}]
```

> `m - n >= 0`